# THEN: since that is so; therefore

Tags: adverbs, conditional-constructions, definition

> 4. in that case; in those circumstances: *If you want to quit, **then** do so. If you're sick, then you should stay in bed. If traffic is heavy, then allow extra time.*
> 5. since that is so;  therefore: *If the car is out of gas, **then** it won't start. You have, then, found the mistake? You are leaving tonight then. The case, then, is closed*
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/definition/then

I can't comprehend the purported difference the dictionary tries to get through.

Comment: In (4) there is an optional action, a choice, decision, but in (5) there is a result, an unavoidable consequence, a logical conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases mentioned in the question there is a conditional construction using "If {condition} then {result}."

In the examples listed under 4 the condition is something that might or might not happen in the future. You might or might not be sick on any given day, traffic might or might not be heavy. The conditional sentence is advising what the listener should do if the condition becomes true (stay in bed, allow extra time).

In the examples listed under 5, the speaker assumes that the condition has already come true, and states a conclusion that must follow from that situation. The listener is not being given a choice.

In short, case 4 says "If this happens then do that." Case 5 says "Since this has happened, that will follow." or "If this happens, that will follow." Case 5 is not advice, case 4 is. In both cases the phrase after "then" expresses things that follow from the condition. In some examples of case 5 an "if" is not used explicitly, but a condition is still implied.

Other dictionaries might not divide up the uses of "then" in quite this way, but the various examples are all valid.

Answer (score -1):

Meaning 4: When is the instant in the future you decide to quit. It may or may not occur; it is the moment of your action of quitting.

Meaning 5: When is the duration of the car not starting; from now until you give it more gas. The endpoint of (this) when is determined by when (meaning 4) you decide to give the car gas.